# How do I pass a variable from AppleScript to a shell command?

Tags: shell, applescript

So far I have:

```
    do shell script {var}
    "if [[ ! -e /$var/ ]]; then
    mkdir -p $var
    fi"
```

I am getting an error of "Command not found"

I know I need to escape something, I'm just not sure where.

Var needs to be passed to the shell command, and create the directory in the specified folder if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is, e.g.:

```
set var to "/path/to/directory/subdirectory"
do shell script "mkdir -p " & var's quoted form
```

You do not need to test whether of not it already exists because of the use of the `-p` *option* with the `mkdir` *command*.

From the manual page for `mkdir`:

> ```
> -p      Create intermediate directories as required.  If this option is not specified, the full path
>         prefix of each operand must already exist.  On the other hand, with this option specified, no
>         error will be reported if a directory given as an operand already exists.  Intermediate
>         directories are created with permission bits of rwxrwxrwx (0777) as modified by the current
>         umask, plus write and search permission for the owner.
> ```